# UserManager asp.net Core 2.0: Connection was not closed. 'Connecting'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm encountering a persistent problem, about 30% of the cases, when generating a JWT token.

The original setup is using Dependency Injection, but for error finding, I instantiate Usermanager 'fresh' in the following code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("token")]
public async Task<BaseResult> Token(string email, string password)
{
    if (email == null) return new BaseResult(BaseResult.ResultCodes.InvalidInput, "not a user");
    //var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(email);
    using (UserManager<User> usermanager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new UserContext()), null,
        new PasswordHasher<User>(), null, null, null, null, null, null))
    {
        User user = await usermanager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        if (user == null)
            return new BaseResult(BaseResult.ResultCodes.NotFound, "user not found");

        if (usermanager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, password) !=
            PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
            return new BaseResult(BaseResult.ResultCodes.InvalidInput, "password incorrect");

        var token = await GetJwtSecurityToken(user);

        return new TokenResult(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token), token.ValidTo);
    }
//{
    //    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
    //    expiration = token.ValidTo
    //});
}
```

The exception gets thrown on usermanager.FindByEmailAsync(email) 30% of the cases, and reads:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The connection was not closed. The
>   connection's current state is connecting.'

As the context is created in the line above, this error I do not understand. Considering the SQL server not fully finalized from a previous request, although it happens most frequently when freshly starting.

information purposes: my context:

```
public sealed class UserContext:IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public UserContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer($"Server =PC; Database =PFUsers; Trusted_Connection = True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");



        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Although for debugging circumvented, but when using DI, the relevant startup section is:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<UserContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);



services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the MultipleActiveResultSets=true; from the connection string solved it.

For a token request MARS is counterproductive (overhead for a single request)